# createEvent calendar MicrosoftAPI without notification

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

is possible with this Graph API create a calendar event with attendee but don't send the email notify?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http